# udev goto and label

Tags: scripting, udev

Should I use the `goto` and `label` in the same file only or is it possible to use it in separate files while writing rules for `udev`?

Does the following code valid?

```
$ cat 05-some.rules
GOTO="other_label"

$ cat 10-other.rules
LABEL="other_label"
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old question, but I am investigating the same thing and thought I would share my findings.

First, all my testing has been with udev version 147.

I have only been able to use a GOTO with a LABEL that is in the same file.  I haven't read anywhere that GOTOs and LABELs must be in the same file, but in my testing, if I have a rule that includes a GOTO to a LABEL in a different file, that rule will be skipped.

Also, I have seen an error when using `udevadm test`:

> parse_file: GOTO 'label_in_different_file' has no matching label in: '/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules'

It then goes on to read more rules in different files.

I did this with `udev_log="debug"` in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`.